# Sharing a serialized object between applications

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

In application 1 I serialize and deserialize and object and it works fine. I would like however to deserialize an object from application 1 in application 2. I added the class that defines that object to application 2. When I try to deserialize it I get this error:

> Could not find assembly 'WindowsFormsApplication6, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

How do I share a serialized object between two applications then?

Comment: If you are using .NET binary serialization, you'll need to actually be referencing the same underlying type (as in the one from the same DLL). If you need to also transfer to a different type you'll need to use a different serialization protocol.

Comment: You need to put the definition of the serialized class into a separate class library assembly, which you reference from both the applications (thereby sharing the class definition).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the definition for the serializable object into a separate assembly and then add a reference to the shared assembly to each project.  (The formatter is adding a reference to the assembly in your first project - they must in fact refer to the same class, not just an identical copy of the class)

Comment: Good solution. Do note that this creates a tight coupling as both versions must use the same referenced assembly. You must review versioning.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `BinaryFormatter`, then it *includes the full type name* in the data, which includes the assembly that the DTO is in (types are always defined by their assembly). One option here is to create a separate DTO library that you reference from each - but note that `BinaryFormatter` is still pretty unreliable when it comes to versioning: I have seen people lose data because they edited their DTO and everything stopped working.

I would strongly advise using a non-type-dependent serializer; for example, `XmlSerializer` /  `DataContractSerializer` / `JSON.NET` / ServiceStack's `JsonSerializer`, or protobuf-net. All of these will work fine but importantly *will not fight you*, in two different ways:

- they are very versioning-friendly
- they don't care if you move types between assemblies

Even *with* this, it is probably most convenient to maintain a separate DTO assembly for the serialized types, but it doesn't *force* you to. Ultimately, since these serializers are all happy to work cross-OS / cross-version / cross-language / cross-CPU, the mere fact of "different assemblies" is very much a "meh, whatever".

Key takeaway: `BinaryFormatter` can be brittle. I never recommend it for anything except in-flight data (for example, remoting between two `AppDomain` instances). I certainly wouldn't use it for anything that is persisted for any length of time, because I simply can't guarantee that I'll be able to reload it in the future.

Comment: Do any of those other serializers allow you to serialize stored image object like system.drawing.bitmap?

Comment: @Andy i would say that you're solving the wrong problem there. The bitmap class is implementation. What you should be serializing is the byte[] that is the actual image payload (presumably in a well known format). Most serializers can handle a byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing things currently

```
    public sealed class VersionDeserializer : SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            var assemVer1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
            var deserializeType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemVer1));

            return deserializeType;
        }
    }

    private object FromByteArray(byte[] data)
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter
        {
            Binder = new VersionDeserializer()
        };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
```